# Sending key value pair object to server side codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Sending key value pair object to server side codebehind .
How to send from javascript?
How to receive in C# codebehind.

### Edit 1

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function ABC() 
   { 
       var dict = []; 
       dict.push({ key: "testkey" ,// Key Value 
       value: "myVal" // "the value" });
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show us please how are you created that Key-value pair object in Javascript, Its schema and all.

Comment: Yes
<script type="text/javascript">
         function ABC() {
             var dict = []; 

 dict.push({
                         key: "testkey" ,// Key Value
                         value: "myVal"  // "the value"
                     });

Comment: You could convert that to a JSON string and Convert it back on the server. It could be passed to your page using a [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: what do you want to do with java-script values on the C#?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send some data back to the server and then get the process result you can use jquery to issue an ajax call and pass whatever you want to pass in the content

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can use Newtonsoft.Json to parse the content into the dictionary on the server